# Convert TIFF files to XYZ files with Lat Long and Depth with GDAL

Tags: gdal-translate, xyz

I am hoping to get some advice on converting a GEO TIFF file to an XYZ File with Lat and Long positions instead of Northing and Easting positions.
I am very new to GDAL, but I have been able to convert a Geo Tiff file to  CSV but the positions are in UTM.
How can I convert my files to XYZ with Lats and Longs?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 2):

[`gdalwarp`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html) will reproject from UTM to geographic (lon, lat)

Assuming your tif has a CRS defined:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -of XYZ in.tif out.csv
```

If it doesn't, you'll need to tell GDAL what the CRS is:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:???? -t_srs EPSG:4326 -of XYZ in.tif out.csv
```

Where ???? is the [EPSG code](https://epsg.io/) for your UTM projection.

Comment: Hello I very much appreciate your reply. Unfortunately I am very new to GDAL and not very knowledgable of it's functions. I am still trying to get my head around it all. Thanks